# Value of type '[NSManagedObject]' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Tags: xcode, swift2

Hi I'm trying to fix SugarRecord a great way to use CoreData and iCloud.

I'm getting this error above with the following method:

```
 public func find(finder: SugarRecordFinder) -> SugarRecordResults
    {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = SugarRecordCDContext.fetchRequest(fromFinder: finder)



        var objects = [NSManagedObject]()
        do{
              objects = try self.contextCD.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

        }
        catch
        {

        }
        if objects == nil  {
            objects = [NSManagedObject]()
        }

        return SugarRecordResults(results: SugarRecordArray(array: objects), finder: finder)
    }
```

The error is on the line - `if objects == nil  {`

Though after searching the net I couldn't find a way to fix this.  Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Remember you can check nil for only optionals, in your case objects is not optional, and that is why you get this error. Instead check if objects contain any items in it.

Answer (score 1):

`executeFetchRequest` return always an array. If nothing could be found the array is empty.

Just delete

```
if objects == nil  {
   objects = [NSManagedObject]()
}
```

A better syntax is

```
public func find(finder: SugarRecordFinder) -> SugarRecordResults
{

  let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = SugarRecordCDContext.fetchRequest(fromFinder: finder)
  do {
    let objects = try self.contextCD.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    return SugarRecordResults(results: SugarRecordArray(array: objects), finder: finder)
  }
  catch let error as NSError {
    // do error handling
    return SugarRecordResults()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi that's great.  Though I'm getting an error on  return SugarRecordResults()